# How do I call a Win32 DLL void** parameter using Win32::API?

Tags: windows, perl

I have a Windows DLL that I want to call from Perl. The prototype for the exported function is:

```
int __stdcall func(const char*, int, int, int, double, double, void**);
```

The last parameter returns a pointer to an object that is allocated in the function.

The perl code –

```
my $dll_path = "../stage/test_dll.dll";

my $dll_func = new Win32::API($dll_path,
                'func',
                'PIIIDDP', 'I');

my $data = "test something here";
my $pResult = 0;

my $rc = $ dll_func ->Call($data, 0, 0, 9, 0.6, 0.3, $pResult);
```

An error message popped up saying that the memory can’t be written.  Maybe I can’t use P to represent void**?  I read through all the documentation and could not locate a single example that uses void** parameter. Help!

Answer (score 2):

The variable associated with a `P` parameter must be a pre-allocated *string* variable, not an integer.  Try something like:

```
my $pResult = "\0" x 8;   # Just in case we're 64-bit

my $rc = $ dll_func ->Call($data, 0, 0, 9, 0.6, 0.3, $pResult);
```

`$pResult` will then contain the pointer to the object.  You'll probably need to use `unpack` to extract it.

You don't say what you need to do with the object.  If you need to pass it to other DLL functions as a `void*`, you'll probably need to unpack it as a `long` and use `N` instead of `P` in the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [swig](http://www.swig.org/) would do it. Maybe you will find your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be off base, but the `Inline::C` module offers a pretty good interface into user libraries, and within Perl and C you can come up with all kinds of workarounds to passing data through a `void**` pointer.

```
use Inline C => DATA => LIBS => '-L../stage -ltest_dll';

my $data = "test something here";
my $rc = func_wrapper($data, 0, 0, 9, 0.6, 0.3);
my $p = get_pointer();
printf "func() set a pointer value of 0x%x\n", $p;    

__END__
__C__

#include <stdio.h>

int func(const char *, int, int, int, double, double, void **);    
void* pointer_value;

long get_pointer()
{
    return (long) pointer_value;
}

/*
 * Wraps func() in test_dll library.
 */
int func_wrapper(const char *s, int i1, int i2, int i3, double d1, double d2)
{
    void *p = (void *) "some pointer";
    int rval = func(s, i1, i2, i3, d1, d2, &p);

    /* func() may have changed  p  as a side effect */
    /* for demonstation, save it to a long value that can be retrieved with
       the  get_pointer()  function. There are other ways to pass the pointer
       data into Perl. */
    pointer_value = p;
    printf("The pointer value from func() is %p\n", p);
    return rval;
}
```

If Inline::C looks interesting to you, the Inline::C-Cookbook page on CPAN is also indispensable.